# ASP.NET MVC Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository

Hi I'm building a very simple search system using ASP.NET MVC. I had it originally work by doing all the logic inside the controller but I am now moving the code piece by piece into a repository. Can anyone help me do this. Thanks.

Here is the original Action Result that was in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(String query)
        {
            var ArticleQuery = from m in _db.ArticleSet
                               select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {
                ArticleQuery = ArticleQuery.Where(m => m.headline.Contains(query) orderby m.posted descending);
            }

            return View(ArticleQuery.ToList());
        }
```

As you can see, the Index method is used for both the initial list of articles and also for the search results (they use the same view).

In the new system the code in the controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.ListAll());
    }
```

The Repository has the following code:

```
public IList<Article> ListAll()
{
    var ArticleQuery = (from m in _db.ArticleSet

                        orderby m.posted descending select m);

    return ArticleQuery.ToList();
}
```

and the Interface has the following code:

```
public interface INewsRepository
{
    IList<Article> ListAll();
}
```

So what I need to do is now add in the search query stuff into the repository/controller methods using this new way. Can anyone help? Thanks.

**EDIT: The INewsRespository file as it looks now:**

```
namespace MySuperAwesomeApp.Models
{
    public interface INewsRepository
    {
        IList<Article> ListAll();

        //Article Details(int id);

        //Article Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]Article articleToCreate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface `INewsRepository` needs to have the following added:

```
IList<Article> Search(string query);
```

#### Repository

Then in the `NewsRepository` that implements `INewsRepository`:

```
public IList<Article> INewsRespository.Search(string query)
{
    var articleQuery = (from m in _db.ArticleSet
                        where m.headline.Contains(query)
                        orderby m.posted descending select m).ToList();
}
```

In the controller, you handle the case where the query doesn't contain information:

#### Controller

```
//just for this example. You should look at DI/IoC for Real World Usage.
INewsRepository repository; 
public ActionResult ListArticles(string query)
{
    repository = new NewsRepository();
    List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        articles = repository.ListAll();
    }
    else 
    { 
        articles = repository.Search(query);
    }
    return View(articles);
}
```

Comment: What happens if they haven't done a search though? As I don't seen any SQL outside of the If statement? OR do I add this code below my current public Ilist? as I have just replaced it with yours.

Comment: @Cameron You can handle the 'no query' in the controller; the Repository Search should be 'dumb' about what it handles.

Comment: This doesn't work as it complains that Search has no return value.

Comment: If I add `return articleQuery;` to the code it fixes it. However in the controller I get the error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<CHT2520_u0558234_1a.Models.Article>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CHT2520_u0558234_1a.Models.Article>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\cameron\Desktop\CHT2520-u0558234-1b\CHT2520-u0558234-1a\Controllers\HomeController.cs 33 28 CHT2520-u0558234-1a

Comment: The bug is that List<T> inherits from IList<T> but not the other way around.  Therefore, when repository.ListAll() returns an IList<T>, it cannot implicitly convert that object to a List<T>.  To resolve this issue, change the two lines: articles = repository.ListAll().ToList(); and articles = repository.Search(query).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code samples in the answer to this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570592/asp-net-mvc-form-post-and-paging/4570671#4570671)** - hope they will help you...

Answer (score 0):

George was close, but his code won't compile (articleQuery is out of scope at the return)

```
// public IList<Article> IRespository.Search(string query)
public IList<Article> Search(string query)
{
    var articleQuery = (from m in _db.ArticleSet orderby m.posted descending select m);
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        ? articleQuery.ToList()  // I'm not 100% sure if ToList is required
        : articleQuery.Where(m => m.headline.Contains(query)).ToList();
}
```

UPDATE:
Ok, your code should ultimately look like this:

```
public interface INewsRepository
{
    IList<Article> Search(string query);
    IList<Article> ListAll();  // You need this too, right?
}

public class NewsRepository : INewsRepository
{
    public IList<Article> Search(string query)
    {
        // Code as above.
    }

    public IList<Article> ListAll()
    {
        // Code as in your question.
    }
}
```

Update 2 (@Cameron url question)

Throw the following code into your controller for a moment and see what result you get:

```
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
    Response.Write("The Query string was :" + query);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

And see what you get.  If you don't see some message, then you must be routing to another controller/action.  If you get nothing, try http://localhost:8888/home/index?query=henry

Comment: What is IRepository.Search referencing as my repository is called NewsRepository and my interface is called INewsRepository so should that be changed?

Comment: And Visual Studio is complaining about that very thing saying that IRepository cannot be found.

Comment: Actually, you can change IRepository.Search to just Search.  An implicitly defined interface member is hidden unless referencing the object as the interface.  So, new NewsRepository().Search("x") is actually not a valid call, but ((INewsRepository) new NewsRepository()).Search("x") would work.

TL;DR just call the method Search()

Comment: Tried that, but VS claimed that it does not implement interface member

Comment: This compiles but the search returns the full results no matter what the query. What would the URL be? As the current system does this: `localhost:8888/?query=henry` is this incorrect for the above code?

Comment: @ARM I just chose to handle it differently than you did. I also fixed the bug. Someone else edited my answer to change my intent, so I edited it again to clarify everything.

Comment: @George There was nothing wrong with the way you did it originally other than the fact it wouldn't compile.  I just changed it to my coding style when I added my own answer which would compile.

Comment: It compiles but your code ARM does not return the correct results. It just returns the full list.

Comment: Have you tried the change to your Action and seen the proper result?  If so, then the only other thing I can think of is that headline.Contains("x") translates to "Where headline like '%x%' " which might return more results than you expect.

Answer (score -2):

This should do the trick:

```
public IList<Article> SearchByTitle(string query){
    var q=_db.ArticleSet;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))    
        q=q.Where(a=>a.Title.Contains(query));
    return q.OrderBy(x=>x.Title).ToList();
}
```

---

And You might benefit from investigating my current search implementation. There is no paging though and it's more like filtering instead of searching. It uses Linq to NHibernate underneath.

Html:

```
@model SearchCriteria
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Applications",FormMethod.Post)){
<span>@Html.ShowLink("Search applications...","searchbox")</span>
<fieldset class="searchapplications">
 <legend>@Html.HideLink("Search applications:","searchbox",container:"fieldset")</legend>
 <table class="alignright" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.ProjectIndex)
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.OpeningStatus)
   <td>
   Duration from @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.DurationFrom)
   to @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.DurationTo)
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.Acronym)
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.AdmStatus)
   <td>
   Requested grant from @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.RequestedGrantFrom)
   to @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.RequestedGrantTo)
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.Priority)
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.EligStatus)
   <td>
   Score from @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.QualScoreFrom)
   to @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.QualScoreTo)
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.Applicant)
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.QualStatus)
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   @Html.TDInputFor(x=>x.JMCDecision)
   <td colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SortBy)
 @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SortAsc)
 <br />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ApplicationsController{
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(SearchCriteria input){
   if(input==null) input=Session[Critkey] as SearchCriteria??new SearchCriteria();
   Session[Critkey]=input;
   var applications=_applications.Search(input);
   var mapped=this.MapList<Application,ApplicationModel>(applications);
   return View(new SearchModel {Applications=mapped,SearchCriteria=input});
 }
}
```

And repository + `SearchCriteria` class:

```
  public class AllApplications:IAllApplications{    
    public IEnumerable<Application> Search(SearchCriteria inp){
      var c=_session.Query<Application>();
      c=ApplicationSearchEagerLoading.Attach(c);
      var q=c.AsQueryable();
      q=AddSearchFilters(inp,q);
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.SortBy)){
        var s=SearchCriteria.SortByTranslations[inp.SortBy];
        q=(inp.SortAsc?q.OrderBy(s):q.OrderByDescending(s)).AsQueryable();
      }
      return q.AsEnumerable();
    }      
    private static IQueryable<Application> AddSearchFilters
       (SearchCriteria inp,IQueryable<Application> q){
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.Acronym))
        q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Acronym.Contains(inp.Acronym));
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.Applicant))
        q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Applicant.Name.Contains(inp.Applicant));
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.Priority))
        q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Priority.Name.Contains(inp.Priority));
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.ProjectIndex))
        q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.ProjectIndex.Contains(inp.ProjectIndex));
      if(inp.OpeningStatus!=null)
        q=q.Where(a=>a.OpeningStatus==inp.OpeningStatus);
      if(inp.AdmStatus!=null)
        q=q.Where(a=>a.AdmCheck.Status==inp.AdmStatus);
      if(inp.EligStatus!=null)
        q=q.Where(a=>a.EligCheck.Status==inp.EligStatus);
      if(inp.QualStatus!=null)
        q=q.Where(a=>a.QualAssessmentStatus==inp.QualStatus);
      if(inp.JMCDecision!=null)
        q=q.Where(a=>a.JMCDecision==inp.JMCDecision);
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.DurationFrom)
         &&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.DurationTo))                   
      q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Description
                .DurationInMonths>=inp.DurationFrom.ExtractNumber()
             &&a.Project.Description
                .DurationInMonths<=inp.DurationTo.ExtractNumber());
      else{
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.DurationFrom))
          q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Description
             .DurationInMonths>=inp.DurationFrom.ExtractNumber());
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inp.DurationTo))               
          q=q.Where(a=>a.Project.Description
            .DurationInMonths<=inp.DurationTo.ExtractNumber());
      }              
      //...
      return q;
    }
  }

  public class SearchCriteria{
    internal static Dictionary<string,Func<Application,object>>
    SortByTranslations=new Dictionary<string,Func<Application,object>>
                         {
                           {"ProjectIndex",x=>x.Project.IndexNr},
                           {"Acronym",x=>x.Project.Acronym},
                           {"Applicant",x=>x.Project.Applicant.Name},
                           {"Priority",x=>x.Project.Priority.Name},
                           {"OpeningStatus",x=>x.OpeningStatus},
                           {"AdmStatus",x=>x.AdmCheck.Status},
                           {"EligStatus",x=>x.EligCheck.Status},
                           {"QualStatus",x=>x.QualAssessmentStatus},
                           {"JMCDecision",x=>x.JMCDecision},
                         };
    public string RequestedGrantTo{get;set;}
    public string RequestedGrantFrom{get;set;}
    public string DurationFrom{get;set;}
    public string DurationTo{get;set;}
    public string QualScoreFrom{get;set;}
    public string QualScoreTo{get;set;}
    public QualAssessmentStatus QualStatus{get;set;}
    public EligCheckStatus EligStatus{get;set;}
    public AdmCheckStatus AdmStatus{get;set;}
    public OpeningStatus OpeningStatus{get;set;}
    public JMCDecision JMCDecision{get;set;}
    public string Applicant{get;set;}
    public string Priority{get;set;}
    public string Acronym{get;set;}
    public string ProjectIndex{get;set;}
    public string SortBy{get;set;}
    public bool SortAsc{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Massive overkill for what I'm doing though I'm afraid. Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you learn about strategy pattern.  LinqKit will also help turn that monster code into something maintainable.

Comment: @ARM Simpleness over complexity, complexity over complicatedness. You miss the first part. I'd strongly suggest You to avoid over-usage of patterns. For me that "monster code" is few lines of completely dumb and encapsulated (almost... criteria is tied with search method) procedural code which can be maintained with ease. Maybe lambdas scares You, dunno...

Comment: Lambdas are not the problem; expressions are not the problem.  Having 10+ if statements is the problem.

Comment: @ARM is having 10+ one liner classes better?

Comment: Yes, altho they're generally 2 liners ;)

Comment: @ARM but LinqKit looks interesting. Will take a closer look. Thanks.